# How to declare a variable as given Type in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, interface, declare

Please help me to resolve this little task: how to declare a variable as **given type**. In this case - interface.

I guess, the answer is simple, but I don't know it, and Google don't too.
I tried everything, but I can't resolve it.

Thank you.

---

```
Public Interface IMyInterface
        Property MyProperty
End Interface

    Public Sub MySimpleSub()
        Dim tType As System.Type = GetType(IMyInterface)
        Call SubAcceptsInterface(tType)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SubAcceptsInterface(ByVal tType As System.Type)
        Dim arrMyArray() As tType= {} ' <-- here's an error: Error 1 Type 'tType' is not defined.
    End Sub
```

Comment: You probably want to have a [Generic implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-types). You should post a description of what this Interface is used for, in your code and what practical problem you're trying to solve (not what you came up with to solve it).

Comment: It's a plugin system. I have several interaces to do smth with db: export, import records etc.

Comment: `GetType(IMyInterface)` will always be `IMyInterface`. Do you rather want the type which _implements_ `IMyInterface`?

Comment: I simplified this part of code. There's no problem to declare this way: Dim arrMyArray() As IMyInterface= {}, but in this case I'll write almost the same code for each Interface.

Comment: Ooops, I answered from my Another account))

Comment: `Public Sub SubAcceptsInterface(Of T)() Dim arrMyArray() As T` and call it with `SubAcceptsInterface(Of IMyInterface) ... SubAcceptsInterface(Of IMyInteface2) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a type of a class/structure/interface to a function, you can template the function like this:

```
Public Sub SubAcceptsInterface(Of tType)()
    Dim arrMyArray() As tType = {} 'This should declare fine
End Sub
```

Pass the tType parameter of the template like this:

```
Public Sub MySimpleSub()
    SubAcceptsInterface(Of IMyInterface)()
End Sub
```